# Flask cannot change the hostname

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to use flask integrate stripe checkout. It can startup fine for default port and 127.0.0.1/localhost. I try to change server host because localhost does not allow access from the remote server. But it does not work after I change. 
Would I know how to change it? Thanks a lot!

details inform:

> Flask 0.12.2 Python 2.7.5 (default, May  3 2017, 07:55:04)

My change:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = '*:5000'
```

Comment: need more explanation to give suggestions.

Comment: to change the port app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=5001)

Comment: thanks @Shiva. it works.

Answer (score 3):

It works after making this change -

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, threaded=True, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple:

1) Go to this website : https://www.whatismyip.com/ ->find your IP address.

2) your flask app.run code should look something like this:

```
app.run(host = 'your global ip from whatismyip', port = '5000')
```

After the above step restart your server, and try to hit your Flask Server remotely, it should work .